# how to copy file from one slave machine to another using jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

my .apk file gets generated on a slave machine A, now I have to copy to it to my slave machine B. I want it to be copied via jenkins job

Answer (score 0):

I use `scp`.

```
 sh "scp -P 22 build/path/example.apk remoteuser@10.10.10.10:/remote/path/example.apk"
```

Setup is requires adding an SSH Key between the two systems and users needed. If they are on the same private network you can use the internal address.

You can also use build variables

```
 sh "scp -P 22 build/path/example-{$BUILD-NUMBER}.apk remoteuser@10.10.10.10:/remote/path/example-{$BUILD-NUMBER}.apk"
```